# Flask app unable to parse suburls

Tags: python, url, flask

I have created a simple heroku app that takes a url as the argument, reads the url data and displays it in the browser. Here is the code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
import urllib2, urlparse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<url>')
def getdata(url):
    url.replace('www.','')
    if url.count('http') == 0:
        url = 'http://'+url
    u = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    nurl = u.geturl()
    response = urllib2.urlopen(nurl).read()
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

When passed a url like `google.com` it works fine. But when passed something like `google.com/images` (I know the url returns 503), it throws a 404 error. When I tried reading suburls normally in my python shell it works just fine.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [*path* option in the `@route`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#variable-rules).  Something like the following should work:

```
@app.route('/<path:url>')
def getdata(url):
    ...
```

Comment: yup. this worked. will accept in 4 minutes. Also reading the document link to figure out how this is different from what I used. Also changing the question title as the question has nothing to do with heroku.

Comment: @ritratt - without the `path` part Flask has to worry about other child paths.  Consider what would happen if you added `@app.route('/com/<path:url>')` as well.  I think that they handle this sort of thing but without the `path`, string segments cannot include a slash.

Comment: Yes I read the link. `path` is a converter allowing slashes in the url.